Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать
Ребёнок меньше всех, или младше всех, если говорить о возрасте ребёнка?

О возрасте корректно: младше всех.
Но у слова "маленький" есть ещё одно значение: малолетний. См. 4. значение. Но даже и в этом значении некорректно говорить: он меньше всех.  
